# UIAlertview message not Showing properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6, uialertview

I'm having a `UIAlertView` and declared as

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NEW_ALBUM" message:@"ENTER_ALBUM_NAME" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
alert.tag = 999;
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

the resultant alert was shown as

[image]

Comment: It seems you are working with NLS string tables here? The strings in the UI are not the strings in the code. Could you please post these string tables also? Maybe a problem there?

Comment: you are right, problem in NLS string table . In that next line chars were included. now fixed, thank you.